# Consequences from Bott Periodicity

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

I have some questions about some arguments used in the discussion about consequnces of Bott periodity in in [*A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology*](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf) by P. May  at page 207. Her the excerpt:

[image]

Following context: Denote $U:= colim_n U(n)$ the infinite unitary group induced via canonical inclusions $U(n) \subset U(n+1)$.

FIRST QUESTION: Why is the loop space $\Omega BU := Hom(S^1, BU)$ $H$- equivalent to $U$?

We know that $BU = E/U$ where $E$ is the unique simply connected universal principal $U$-space and after applying $\pi_0(-)$ functor we obtain $\pi_0(\Omega BU) = \pi_1(E/U)= U$ by covering theory since $E$ is universal cover.

But does this already imply that $\Omega BU $ homotopy equivalent to $U$? $\pi_0$ only counts path components.

SECOND QUESTION: We know that $SU$ - the infinite special unitary group - is the universal cover of $U$ (via colimit argument). Futhermore $\pi_1(U)=\mathbb{Z}$.

Why does it imply that $$\Omega U \cong (\Omega SU) \times \mathbb{Z}$$ as $H$-spaces (remark: $X$ is a $H$-space if there exist a "multiplication" $X \times X \to X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the map of fibrations from the universal principal $U$-bundle over $BU$ to the path-loop fibration on $BU$:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
U @>>> EU @>>> BU \\
@VVV @VVV @| \\
\Omega BU @>>> PBU @>>> BU  
\end{CD}

One can write down a map $EU \to PBU$; thus there is a map $U \to \Omega BU$.  Looking at the long exact sequence in homotopy and using the five-lemma, one deduces that the induced map $U \to \Omega BU$ is a weak homotopy equivalence because $EU \simeq PBU \simeq *$.  (Since both source and target can be equipped with a CW structure, this can be promoted to a homotopy equivalence.)

In general, this shows $\Omega BG \simeq G$ for a topological group $G$.  See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442805/the-loop-space-of-the-classifying-space-is-the-group-omegabg-simeq-g) for more details.

For your second question, there is a short exact sequence of topological groups $$1 \to SU \to U \xrightarrow{\det} S^1 \to 1$$ which is split, so $U \cong SU \rtimes S^1$ as topological groups.  If we ignore the group structure and only care about the topology, then we have a homeomorphism $U \cong SU \times S^1$.  Taking loops on both sides, we get $$\Omega U \cong \Omega SU \times \Omega S^1 \simeq \Omega SU \times \mathbb{Z}$$ as loop spaces, hence as $H$-spaces.

Comment: Thank you for answer. One point iritates me: In the last line you claim (neglecting the left factor $\Omega SU$) that $\Omega S^1 \simeq \mathbb{Z}$. Why does it hold? I think that it only holds after passing to homtopy groups. More precisely we know that the loop space is defined as $\Omega S^1 := Hom(S^1, S^1)$. On the other hand we know that for ***homotopy classes*** holds indeed $[S^1,S^1]=\mathbb{Z}$ where the conection is the path component functor $\pi_0(\Omega S^1 )= [S^1,S^1]$. But I'm not sure why should hold  $\Omega S^1 \simeq \mathbb{Z}$ ***before*** passing to homotopy classes?

Comment: Another remark: Do I understand the argument with the $H$-story correctly that already $U \cong SU \times S^1$ suffice since $\Omega(-)$ endows in a functorial way the spaces with $H$-space structure? And therefore $H$-space property is here equivalent to functoriality of $\Omega(-)$?

Comment: $\Omega S^1$ is homotopy discrete (it has no higher homotopy groups, because $S^1$ has no homotopy groups above degree $1$).  For your second question: if $X \cong Y$, then $\Omega X \cong \Omega Y$ as loop spaces.  You might be concerned about the original multiplication on $X$ and $Y$ if they were groups to begin with, but an Eckmann-Hilton argument would show that the operations coincide.  Finally, note that a loop space equivalence is stronger than a $H$-space equivalence.

Comment: hmmm so for $\Omega S^1 \simeq \mathbb{Z}$ you also implicitely use Whitehead, don't you?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem

Since your homotopy discreteness argument provides that $\Omega S^1$ and $\coprod_{z \in \mathbb{Z}} \{*\} \cong \mathbb{Z}$ have the same homotopy groups. Or did I misunderstood your point?

Comment: Sure that works.  Or you could argue $\Omega S^1 \simeq \Omega K(\mathbb{Z}, 1) \simeq K(\mathbb{Z}, 0) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$, which is basically the same argument.